# HTML formatted text in an email in Java

Tags: java, html, email

```
     try{
        String msg="Happy BirthDay Dear,<b> "+name.toUpperCase()+" </b> !!! Have a Great Day. \n \n Thank You \n Seva Development ";
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        helper.setTo(email);
        helper.setText(msg);
        helper.setSubject("BirthDay");
        mailSender.send(message);

    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

I am trying to bold the name of the user but it displays as it is in the mail as shown in the picture. Ideas or solutions are highly appreciated[image]

Comment: Nothing about this question inherently points to an issue with Spring or that you're using any Spring components.  Additionally I would be shocked if a mail library allowed arbitrary user input to dictate formatting like bold or italic text; that's usually set up in the template explicitly.

Comment: Did you tried my solution ?

Comment: 1) Note that the `String` seen above, uses markup for some of the parts, but also uses line breaks (`\n`) that will be ignored by HTML. 2) `}catch (Exception e){}` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, I have changed two line code, Thank you all for your contribution

```
private void sendEmail(String email,String name) throws Exception{
    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{
                String msg="Dear<b> "+name.toUpperCase()+" </b>,<p> On Behalf of someone we would like to wish you a Many many Happy returns of the day</p> <p style=color:red;>Happy Birthday and Have a Great Day.</p>\n \n Thank You!";

                MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
                helper.setTo(email);
                helper.setText(msg);
                message.setContent(msg, "text/html");                   
                helper.setSubject("BirthDay");
                mailSender.send(message);

            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `helper.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");`

Comment: I tried using your code but it is giving me an error message "Cannot resolve method 'setContent(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `MimeMessageHelper`  .Try below.

```
 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
 helper.setText(msg, true);
```

Use [MimeMessageHelper.setText(emailContent,true)](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. The boolean `true` flag indicates html content.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified content type of mail. In which case it is sent in plain.

Try setting content type

```
helper.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html;  charset=\"utf-8\"");
```

Now when you open this mail with any email client, it will read it in html format.

You can also set multiple formats by using `MimeMultitype`

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
BodyPart messageBodyPart;

// PLAIN TEXT
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(textBody, "text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

// HTML TEXT
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);
```